# Upload Audio file to server and set images from server response

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, jakarta-ee

I need to upload Audio file to the server and show the image from server response. I'm new to java script and ajax. I'm trying to get the audio file from input tag to ajax call but it returns illegal invocation. I need to upload audio file to the java web service and it returns image as a file format so need to show this image file as a  preview. is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance

```
<body>
<form role="form" id="serviceReq" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload File : <input type="file" name="audio"
        id="audioFile" title="Upload File">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div>
    <!-- set Response image from server -->
    <img alt="" id="preImage" src="">
</div>
```

service.request.js

```
$(function() {
var formName = "#serviceReq";
$(formName)
        .on(
                'submit',
                function(e) {
                    var documentData = new FormData();
                    documentData.append('audio', $("#audioFile").prop(
                            'files')[0]);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.support.cors = true;
                    $
                            .ajax({
                                url : 'http://192.168.2.11:8082/SoundWaveService/audioWave/addAudioNew',
                                method : 'POST',
                                crossDomain : true,
                                contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
                                dataType : 'script',
                                data : documentData,
                                beforeSend : function() {
                                },
                                success : function(data) {
                                    /**
                                     * set images to #preImage from server
                                     * response
                                     */
                                },
                                error : function(e) {
                                    alert(e);
                                }
                            });
                });});
```

My service method in java

```
@Path("/addAudioNew")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response insertAudioWaveNew(@FormDataParam("audio") InputStream audioFile) throws Exception {
    File response = null;
    response = fetchService.insertAudioNew(audioFile);
    return Response.ok(response, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachement; filename=\"" + response.getName() + "\"").build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$(function() {
var formName = "#serviceReq";
$(formName).on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var documentData = new FormData();
    documentData.append('audio', $("#audioFile")[0].files[0]);
    $.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://192.168.2.11:8082/SoundWaveService/audioWave/addAudioNew',
        method : 'POST',
        crossDomain : true,
        contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false, //New
        data : documentData,
        beforeSend : function() { },
        success : function(data) {
            /**
             * set images to #preImage from server
             * response
             */
        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
});
});
```

If you use cross domain ajax request your server must add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the response headers.